# Invalid handle exception in call to AStarShortestPath.getPath

Tags: jgrapht

In the execution of the getPath method of AStarShortestPath I am getting exceptions
new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid handle!");

In the graph that is originally created, I added some cold shortcuts by adding segments between every 16th node on what in my model is a kind of long straight road.

It is at the moment not easy to create a small sample code here that would reproduce the problem.
Stack trace:

```
org.jheaps.tree.PairingHeap.decreaseKey(PairingHeap.java:425)
org.jheaps.tree.PairingHeap.access$000(PairingHeap.java:89)
org.jheaps.tree.PairingHeap$Node.decreaseKey(PairingHeap.java:363)
org.jgrapht.alg.shortestpath.AStarShortestPath.expandNode(AStarShortestPath.java:224)
```

But first of all my question is if somebody else saw this exception and if what the solution was in that case.

I am using version 1.4.0 of JGraphT

Update: I may have found the problem: there were edges with very small differences in weight. The difference dipped below the tolerance of the         ToleranceDoubleComparator:  DEFAULT_EPSILON = 1e-9

This made the sorting unpredictable, leading to the error.

Comment: This question is hard to answer: no general answer might exist. There can be many reasons to get a specific error (think about all the different ways that you might end up with a nullpointer exception in Java...). Try to create a small (reproducible!) example that exhibits this error. It could be that there's a bug in the AStarShortestPath implementation, in which case we would like you to submit a [ticket](https://github.com/jgrapht/jgrapht/issues). It could also be that there's an issues with your implementation too (but for that we need to have the example).

Comment: the context where it happens is 100% reproducible, but definitely not small. The search is embedded in a wider context and the graph has 51547 vertices and 127553 edges.
I am thinking how to bring it back to a smaller example that I can post. I found two vertices where the problem occurs with a closed and open list of some 25 nodes, so that is promising. But as I mentioned, perhaps somebody recognized the issue and was able to overcome the problem